# Calculating HMAC

Tags: hmac

I've been trying to learn how HMAC is calculated but seem to be missing something.  According to [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), calling HMAC-SHA1 on an empty key and message should result in a value of `fbdb1d1b18aa6c08324b7d64b71fb76370690e1d`.

I've confirmed it with:

```
$ echo -n "" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac ""

(stdin)= fbdb1d1b18aa6c08324b7d64b71fb76370690e1d
```

Following the pseudocode in the wiki page, I tried running this in bash:

```
ipad=$(printf '\x36%.0s' {1..64})

opad=$(printf '\x5C%.0s' {1..64})

echo -n $opad$(echo -n $ipad | sha1sum | awk '{print $1}') | sha1sum
```

I thought since the key is empty, the inner padded key will just be 64 bytes of `\x36` characters and `\x5C` for the outer padded key. And since the message is also empty, HMAC can be calculated via `SHA1(o_key_pad||SHA1(i_key_pad))`. But it returns a different result. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `sha1sum` is in ASCII to display the hexadecimal digest. HMAC-SHA1 uses the raw, binary output of the hash, not any encoded representation of it. What you have done is equivalent to this:

```
HMACK(m) = hex(H((K ⊕ opad) || hex(H((K ⊕ ipad) || m))))
```

An actual HMAC implementation with key `K`, message `m`, and hash function `H` is defined as:

```
HMACK(m) = H((K ⊕ opad) || H((K ⊕ ipad) || m))
```

Let's try modifying your script to convert hex back into binary with `xxd` and run it in bash:

```
$ ipad=$(printf '\x36%.0s' {1..64})
$ opad=$(printf '\x5C%.0s' {1..64})
$ echo -n ${opad}$(echo -n "$ipad" | sha1sum | awk '{print $1}' | xxd -ps -r) | sha1sum
fbdb1d1b18aa6c08324b7d64b71fb76370690e1d  -
```

Ta da!